# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useContext.register')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

How to solve this error
I m getting the Exception TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'addTodo(title, description).then') the function was working fine and states are aupdating fine but its not working as expected.

HomeScreen.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {AuthContext} from '../navigation/AuthProvider';

export function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  const {register} = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <StatusBar
        hidden={false}
        backgroundColor="#f9fafd"
        barStyle="dark-content"
      />
      <Text>Home Screen </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

AuthProvider.js

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthPrivider = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        login: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
        register: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
        logout: async () => {
          try {
            await auth().signOut();
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
      }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kENS2.png)

Comment: can u show the lines that the `register` is called?

Comment: Register is inside the <AuthContext.Provider

Comment: no, that is where it's defined, but not where it's called.